# Datepicker with weekNumber in a dynamic list

Tags: javascript, datepicker

I have a date picker to input the date in a field in a dynamic list (producing 39 rows and 39 date pickers) I also need to input the weekNumber for each date chosen on each row.

I can get the date to work correctly but the weekNumber is duplicated on all of the 39 rows with the weekNumber for the last date selected which also changes as you enter a new date in one of the other fields, how do I get the week number field to correspond only with the date field on each row.

Code is below.

Thanks in advance

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker ui-80TopTo0Bottom-gradient-content ui-TopToBottom-gradient-header" maxlength="10" size="10">
<input type="text" class="weekNumber" maxlength="2" size="2"/>

$('.datepicker').datepicker({
dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
    $('.weekNumber').val($.datepicker.iso8601Week(new Date(dateText)));
}
});
```

** UPDATE **

I have implemented the fiddle kindly supplied by @riverhorse but the script doesn't create a new id for the following fields in the dynamic list to the #NcampaignScheduled or #NcampaignWeek as you can see from the from the code below. Ive indented the lines I expected to see changes to.

I should note that if I remove ' for (let i = 1; i < 3; i++{ and the closing } ' I get the date picker and week number working correctly and as expected in the 1st row of the dynamic list, with this code included I get no datepicker at all.

Any help is much appreciated, especially @riverhorse

@riverhorse Jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
for (let i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
$('#NcampaignScheduled' + i).datepicker({
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
    onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
        $('#NcampaignWeek' + i).val($.datepicker.iso8601Week(new Date(dateText)));
    }
    });
}
```

```
 <div id="NcampaignArea" class="fluid purple">Wing Road</div>
 <div id="NcampaignCode" class="fluid purple">A1</div>
 <div id="NcampaignQuantity" class="fluid purple">1360</div>
     <input type="text" id="NcampaignScheduled" name="NcampaignScheduled" placeholder="Sch Date"/>
     <input type="text" id="NcampaignWeek" placeholder="Week"/>
 <div id="NcampaignArea" class="fluid purple">Southcott</div>
 <div id="NcampaignCode" class="fluid purple">A2</div>
 <div id="NcampaignQuantity" class="fluid purple">740</div>
    <input type="text" id="NcampaignScheduled" name="NcampaignScheduled" placeholder="Sch Date"/>
    <input type="text" id="NcampaignWeek" placeholder="Week"/>
```

Comment: `$('.weekNumber')` selects all elements with the `weekNumber` class. What you want is to set ids like `weekNumberN` and then in JS use `$('#weekNumber' + i)` where i goes from 1 to 39.

Comment: @riverhorse Thanks for helping, unfortunately I can't get it to work, with your code I don't get the week displayed at all, would you be able to show where to enter the code inside my example, once I get it working correctly I'll happily accept your answer for you. I couldn't see the relevance of the 2nd 'N' in weekNumberN so I tried with and without in case it was a typo.

Comment: Check this out: https://jsfiddle.net/sorelmitra/ryc5ozjb/3/

Comment: Hi @riverhorse thanks for the fiddle you took the trouble to write, sorry to say though I'm still struggling, Ive changed the code slightly now to try and simplify things, however the script is not adding anything to the field id's, I've updated the question with new code and explanation. Thanks again, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Well change the code to add IDs. Or maybe I'm not following you... You seem to have a new problem now. The fiddle I put solved your original one.

Comment: @riverhorse It's the same problem, the page gets a list of areas dynamically, in this case it's 39, each of the 39 rows returned needs to have a date picker and week number fields, I understand that the code works in the fiddle but if you look at the code above the 2nd #NcampaignScheduled & #NcampaignWeek aren't adding anything to the id's which is what the code was supposed to do (as I understand it) instead it stops the date picker from showing up. Sorry but I have no knowledge or understanding of Jquery at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now solved my problem and full credit has to go to @riverhorse whose JQuery code supplied in his fiddle now works like a charm, all I had to do was work out how to increment the dynamic id's, the resolve is shown below in case it helps somebody else out in the future:

```
<?php $scheduled = 0; ?>
<?php $week = 0; ?>

<div class="NcampaignScheduled">
  <input type="text" id="NcampaignScheduled' . ++$scheduled . '" placeholder="Sch Date" maxlength="10" size="10"/>
    </div>
J<div class="NcampaignWeek">
  <input type="text" id="NcampaignWeek' . ++$week . '" placeholder="Week" maxlength="2" size="5"/>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
    for (let i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
    $('#NcampaignScheduled' + i).datepicker({
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
    onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
        $('#NcampaignWeek' + i).val($.datepicker.iso8601Week(new Date(dateText)));
    }
    });
}
</script>
```